# Ford Focus TDCI (2003) chokes at red lights

Tags: ford, focus

I've got a problem with my French Ford. I replaced the engine a year ago although I'm not entirely sure the old one is dead (but it's run 380,000**km**).

Anyway, for a couple of months the engine stops very often at red lights and sometimes chokes when I'm accelerating. It feels a bit as if I hit some 10 pounds obstacle.

I really don't know where this can come from. Any hints?

Comment: Is this the Lynx engine? If I remember correctly, this was the first generation of Ford Duratorq engines to have an EGR valve. Could this valve be dirty (full of soot)?

Comment: Well I don't know which engine it is exactly but I do know it's got an EGR. I've been told of this but I wasn't convinced. I'd try do do something about it but I really don't know how.